# Linq query for search entities with many-to-many relationships

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have problem with searching.
So, I have Task entity and Owner Entity. They are in many-to-many relationships.
My target - find all Tasks by some Owner. In entity framework datamodel there's no relationship table as outstanding entity.
I create linq-filter expression, but I can't include in it rule for Owners. I tried to use some lambda expression, but compiler asked me to use simple types and no "Owners".

```
            Expression<Func<Task, bool>> filter = e =>
                (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterData.Title) || e.Title.StartsWith(filterData.Title))
               && (isDueDateSkipped || (DateTime.Compare(dueDate, e.DueDate ?? now) == 0))                       
               && (isCloseDateSkipped || (DateTime.Compare(closeDate, e.CloseDate ?? now) == 0))
               && (isTypeSkipped || e.Type.Id == typeId)
               && (isStatusSkipped || e.Status.Id == statusId)
               && (isPrioritySkipped || e.Priority.Id == priorityId)
               && (isMemberSkipped || e.Member.Id == memberId);
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for my issue:

```
  Expression<Func<Task, bool>> filter = e =>
                   (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterData.Title) || e.Title.StartsWith(filterData.Title))
                   && (isDueDateSkipped || (DateTime.Compare(dueDate, e.DueDate ?? now) == 0))
                   && (isCloseDateSkipped || (DateTime.Compare(closeDate, e.CloseDate ?? now) == 0))
                   && (isTypeSkipped || e.Type.Id == typeId)
                   && (isStatusSkipped || e.Status.Id == statusId)
                   && (isPrioritySkipped || e.Priority.Id == priorityId)
                   && (isMemberSkipped || e.Member.Id == memberId)
                   && (isOwnerSkipped || e.Owners.Select(o => o.Id).Contains(ownerId));
        return filter;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume e is a Task:

```
 Expression<Func<Task, bool>> filter = e =>
            (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterData.Title) || e.Title.StartsWith(filterData.Title))
           && (isDueDateSkipped || (DateTime.Compare(dueDate, e.DueDate ?? now) == 0))                       
           && (isCloseDateSkipped || (DateTime.Compare(closeDate, e.CloseDate ?? now) == 0))
           && (isTypeSkipped || e.Type.Id == typeId)
           && (isStatusSkipped || e.Status.Id == statusId)
           && (isPrioritySkipped || e.Priority.Id == priorityId)
           && (isMemberSkipped || e.Member.Id == memberId)
           && (isOwnerSkipped || TaskOwners.Where(to => to.TaskID == e.TaskID && to.OwnerID == ownerFilter.OwnerID).Count() > 0);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have an error: **The specified type member 'TaskOwners' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.**

Comment: Is that the name of the entity of your many-to-many relationship table? What I've given you is mostly a scetch which you probably need to adapt to your code.